# Properly adding an action to a ContentEntityForm

Tags: forms, 8, entities

I've created an add/edit form for a custom entity type, which extends `Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm`. By default this form always comes with a "Save" button, and a "Delete" button if editing. I've been asked to add a "Cancel" button as well, but can't figure out how this is supposed to be done in Drupal.

I've seen plenty of answers about using `hook_form_alter()`, but nothing that is really working. My current solution is to add

```
$form['cancel'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#weight' => 10001,
    '#submit' => array('cancel_submit'),
    '#value' => t('Cancel'),
);
```

to the form's `form()` function, where `cancel_submit()` is a custom function, but that renders like [image: this] which looks awful.

How can I get the two buttons to be in line with each other? Is there a way to properly add a button to the form actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is relatively simple when you define the form class yourself and one of the reasons Drupal 8 has gone all out on OOP. What you need to do is to extend the form class and implement the `::actions` method. This would look like this:

```
class CustomEntityForm extends ContentEntityForm {
  ...

  protected function actions(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $actions =  parent::actions($form, $form_state);
    $actions['cancel'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Cancel'),
      '#submit' => ['::cancelSubmit'],
    ];
    return $actions;
  }

  public function cancelSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Du custom submit validation
  }

}
```

You could also achieve this with normal form alter, but would need to place the submit button inside the actions element, which is usually called `actions`, fx

```
$form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#weight' => 10001,
  '#submit' => array('cancel_submit'),
  '#value' => t('Cancel'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm attempting your first method, but it's crashing my site with this message: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() must be of the type array, null given, called in {directory}\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm.php on line 206 and defined in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 71 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php)."

Comment: @saramm1 I updated the code in the first method, you should note that code is mostly example code, not meant for copy/paste without edits